i want to verify the following p2pkh transaction
I know to veify the p2pkh transaction we have to place the unlocking script and locking script in a stack and than evalute the stack. In such cases the the scriptpubkey_asm is of the form <OP_DUP OP_HASH160 286eb663201959fb12eff504329080e4c56ae287 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG>.
however the transaction i need to verify also have an additional OP_PUSHBYTES_20 in it.
what exactly i am supposed to do with this.
below is the transaction i need to verify
const transaction = {
  "version": 2,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "fb7fe37919a55dfa45a062f88bd3c7412b54de759115cb58c3b9b46ac5f7c925",
      "vout": 1,
      "prevout": {
        "scriptpubkey": "76a914286eb663201959fb12eff504329080e4c56ae28788ac",
        "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 286eb663201959fb12eff504329080e4c56ae287 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "scriptpubkey_type": "p2pkh",
        "scriptpubkey_address": "14gnf7L2DjBYKFuWb6iftBoWE9hmAoFbcF",
        "value": 433833
      },
      "scriptsig": "4830450221008f619822a97841ffd26eee942d41c1c4704022af2dd42600f006336ce686353a0220659476204210b21d605baab00bef7005ff30e878e911dc99413edb6c1e022acd012102c371793f2e19d1652408efef67704a2e9953a43a9dd54360d56fc93277a5667d",
      "scriptsig_asm": "OP_PUSHBYTES_72 30450221008f619822a97841ffd26eee942d41c1c4704022af2dd42600f006336ce686353a0220659476204210b21d605baab00bef7005ff30e878e911dc99413edb6c1e022acd01 OP_PUSHBYTES_33 02c371793f2e19d1652408efef67704a2e9953a43a9dd54360d56fc93277a5667d",
      "is_coinbase": false,
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "76a9141ef7874d338d24ecf6577e6eadeeee6cd579c67188ac",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 1ef7874d338d24ecf6577e6eadeeee6cd579c671 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2pkh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "13pjoLcRKqhzPCbJgYW77LSFCcuwmHN2qA",
      "value": 387156
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "76a9142e391b6c47778d35586b1f4154cbc6b06dc9840c88ac",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 2e391b6c47778d35586b1f4154cbc6b06dc9840c OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2pkh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "15DQVhQ7PU6VPsTtvwLxfDsTP4P6A3Z5vP",
      "value": 37320
    }
  ]
};


Welcome to crypto SE. This is not the platform for this question try here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/
